# Smarty cat escapes html

Tags: php, escaping, smarty, html-select

I have simple code:

```
{html_checkboxes values=$user_data['names']['id'] output = $user_data['names']['user_name']|cat:' | Status: '|cat:$user_data['names']['status'] escape=false}
```

In array `$user_data['names']['status']` is stored user statuses like `<span style="color: red">User</span>`, so i need to display it like *Username | Status: User* (user in red), but smarty cut it off. Without cat, it there just 1 variable it is all ok.

I also tested `{user_data['names']['status']}`, `"lol"|cat:$user_data['names']['status']` and `$user_data['names']['user_name']|cat:' | Status: '|cat:$user_data['names']['status']` -  it works ok. Where is the problem?

Comment: Geek terms these days.... Smarty Cat escapes html...

Comment: @Mob without cat, it there just 1 variable it is all ok.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the version (Smarty2 / Smarty3) you might need to one of the following:

```
{html_checkboxes values=$user_data.names.id output={$user_data.names.user_name|cat:' | Status: '|cat:$user_data.names.status} escape=false}
```

assign your value to a variable to dumb things down:

```
{assign var="foo" value=$user_data.names.user_name|cat:' | Status: '|cat:$user_data.names.status}
{html_checkboxes values=$user_data.names.id output=$foo escape=false}
```

or use {capture} for more complex things (removing the need for the `cat` modifier):

```
{capture assign="foo"}{$user_data.names.user_name|cat:' | Status: '|cat:$user_data.names.status}{/capture}
{html_checkboxes values=$user_data.names.id output=$foo escape=false}
```